# How to train caffe model in torch

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, torch

I use [torch-caffe-binding](https://github.com/szagoruyko/torch-caffe-binding) to load caffe model to torch, and the example shows that

```
require 'caffe'
net = caffe.Net('deploy.prototxt', 'bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel', 'test') 
input = torch.FloatTensor(10,3,227,227)
output = net:forward(input)
gradOutput = torch.FloatTensor(10,1000,1,1)
gradInput = net:backward(input, gradOutput)
```

but when i use backward to train the net,no matter how many times to train it,the output doesn't change when input same data.so how to train the caffe model,thanks in advance. 
**add:**
i'm sorry that i didn't say clearly.my code like this:

```
caffenet = caffe.Net('test.prototxt','test2.caffemodel','train')
caffe_output = caffenet:forward(input)
local predParts=netPred:forward(caffe_output)
netPred:backward(caffe_output, gradPred)
caffenet:backward(input,g)
```

`netPred` is a torch net,and`caffenet` is a net that remove the last loss layer.but i set the second last layer `loss_weight=1`and console shows all layers like this`ip1 needs backward computation.`,but i check the output never changed when i use `backward`.and even i add the loss layer it also didn't work.

Comment: Usually in caffe, the "deploy" net is for **test** only: that is, it does not require input labels and it does **not** have a loss. You need the "train" prototxt

Comment: i'm sorry that i didn't say clearly.my code like this:

Comment: `caffenet = caffe.Net('test.prototxt','test2.caffemodel','train')  caffe_output = caffenet:forward(input)  local predParts=netPred:forward(caffe_output)    netPred:backward(caffe_output, gradPred)  caffenet:backward(input,g)` `netPred` is a torch net,and`caffenet` is a net that remove the last loss layer.but i set the second last layer `loss_weight=1`and console shows all layers like this`ip1 needs backward computation.`,but i check the output never changed when i use `backward`.and even i add the loss layer it also didn't work.

Comment: loss_weight=1 does not mean you have a loss layer. You need to output a scalar loss value

Comment: please do not post code in comments: it cannot be read clearly. edit your post to reflect your comment